# Expected & recived data are not match

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am trying to create a test case for the following function. I want to match the data as expected.

[image: error in jest test]

Here is my test code:

generic.test.ts

```
describe("generateSalamWelcome", () => {
  it("salam queries", async () => {
    const getRestaurantQueriesMultipleMock = jest
      .spyOn(templateUtils, "getRestaurantQueriesMultiple")
      .mockImplementation((): any => {
        // console.log("coming from mock...");
        return Promise.resolve({enOnly: false, bnOnly: false, });
      });
    const result = await generateSalamWelcome(value);
    if (result) {
      console.log(result[0].data);
    }
    expect(getRestaurantQueriesMultipleMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result).toEqual(strings.salamWelcomeEn);
  });
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your expectation? `expect(result[0].data.message.text).toEqual(strings.salamWelcomeEn);`

Comment: not work, show message error